# Maven Not Downloading Plugin

Tags: java, node.js, maven, jenkins, maven-3

I'm trying to set up Maven on a node project I'm working on for build reasons. I've added the following minimal `pom.xml` file to the project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>project.id</groupId>
<artifactId>project-title</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>project-name</name>
<description>Project Description</description>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <!--<executable>npm start</executable> -->
            <executable>echo 'HELLO'</executable>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

However, now when I run `mvn install` it starts, begins to download the plugin but never finishes. Here is the command and console:

```
$ mvn install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project-name 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.pom
```

Now when I `curl` or visit the address, I can see the xml file perfect. Can anyone give me any direction on how to head from here? I'm using Maven 3.1.1 and Java 7.

Comment: mvn dont throw any exception ??

Comment: Nope, but after fooling around a bit more I think it may have to do with proxies on our network  -- which is strange bc it was reachable by curl

Comment: pom.xml seems gud,may be network firewall arising it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `settings.xml` file, which Maven looks for in the following locations and order:

- `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`
- `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`

There is a section in the settings.xml file for proxies and mirrors, which may be why you're seeing inconsistent bhavior between `curl` and `mvn`

**EDIT**
See Maven docs on [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) for more details:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>myproxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <username>proxyuser</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Comment: Oh, so you can set up your settings file to mimic your network proxies?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it takes long time for maven to understand network problems. I saw situations when it "hangs" for 15 minutes on secured network without proper config for proxy. 
I didn't use curl, but I wonder if it can use system proxy settings? Maven should be configured separately, he doesn't understand them.